# WKPreferences isElementFullscreenEnabled disables screen rotation

Tags: ios, swift, macos, webkit, wkwebview

Starting on `iOS 15.4` and `macOS 12.3` `WKPreferences` has the new property [isElementFullscreenEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkpreferences/3917769-iselementfullscreenenabled), part of `WKWebViewConfiguration`, which enables JavaScript to make elements full-screen in a `WKWebView`, but enabling it on an iOS app that only supports *Portrait Orientation* disables screen rotation on full-screen for any playback (YouTube videos for example).

This is important if you have an app that only supports portrait mode but wants screen rotation when playing a video on full-screen (going back to portrait when the video finishes).

Having `isElementFullscreenEnabled = false`, you can still play videos on full-screen (at least on YouTube), and it allows screen rotation but disables making other HTML elements full-screen.

Important to note that on **macOS**, `preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true` is needed if you want full-screen videos.

#### Question

Is there a workaround to have both: `isElementFullscreenEnabled = true` and screen rotation for videos on **iOS** when only supporting portrait mode?